# Which version(s) of ArcGIS API are compatible with ArcGIS 10.2?

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-10.2, arcgis-silverlight-api, silverlight

I'm working on an older Esri-Silverlight4 solution and trying to use services in ArcGIS 10.2.

A lot of it works, but I'm seeing some different behavior(10.0 was much more lenient with its parameters) and it occurred to me that `ArcGIS API for Silverlight v2.4` might not be compatible with ArcGIS 10.2.

Is there matrix list somewhere on esri.com that shows compatibility between ArcGIS Server and Silverlight clients?

Comment: Hm, I guess every service 10.1+ should be working fine (new architecture introduced).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

based on the ESRI ArcGIS API for Silverlight docs for [3.1](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/silverlight-api/concepts/#/What_s_new_in_3_1/0166000000mq000000/) and [3.3](https://developers.arcgis.com/silverlight/info/whats-new.htm), I believe you want 3.2 or newer, Silverlight 5, and Visual Studio 2012 or newer to build apps to hit 10.2 servers.